# SQL Server : computed column error in dateadd formula

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, ssms, calculated-columns

These are the columns (simplifying):

```
myDate as Date
theMonths as int
```

Then I create a computed column `finalDate` in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2, with this formula:

```
(dateadd(month, theMonths, myDate))
```

Very simple. But there is an error:

> Error validating formula

The error occurs only if I insert the formula through the integrated assistant in Management Studio. Not occurs when create column through T-SQL query.

If I change `myDate` type to `Datetime`, there's no error, but I can't change the table structure.

I try this:

```
(dateadd(month, theMonths, CONVERT(Datetime, myDate)))
```

The error persists.

I created the column directly in T-SQL using the following:

```
ADD [finalDate] AS (dateadd(month,[theMonths],[myDate])) PERSISTED
```

It works fine, the column is created, the data is computed when insert-update. The problem is in the Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[test]
(
    myDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
    theMonths INT NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    finalDate AS (DATEADD(MONTH, theMonths, myDate)) PERSISTED
)

INSERT INTO dbo.[test] (myDate, theMonths)
VALUES('20130101', 5) 

SELECT * FROM dbo.[test]
```

Comment: I run your query and it works fine, creates the table and column is calculated correctly.
Then I go to the database browser in SQL Management Studio, select the table and, for example, created a new column using menu comands. I try, and keep the error (Error validating formula).
Everything works goods, but there is a message which, of course, is unacceptable to my bosses.